# Spring Boot JPA custom Query with OneToMany

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm building a Twitter-like application in Spring Boot. I'm trying to generate a timeline for a user. I've made a custom query for this and added it into my `repository` which extends `CrudRepository<Account, Long>`. When I try to start the application I'm receiving the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: account_following is not mapped
```

The account_following table is a `@OneToMany` from `Account` to `Account` as you can see in the code below. I'm not sure how to put the `account_following` into the query.

**AccountRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT t FROM Tweet t, account_following k WHERE k.following_id = t.owner_id AND k.account_ID = :account_ID AND k.following_id IN (SELECT following_ID FROM account_following WHERE account_id = :account_ID) ORDER BY unixdate DESC")
    public List<Tweet> generateTimeline(@Param("account_ID") Long account_ID);

}
```

**Account.java**

```
@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String username;

    @Transient
    private String password;

    private String location;

    private String description;

    private String website;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Account> following;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tweet> tweets;
}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>kwetter</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <!--Spring Boot-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!--JAVAX-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!--DB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The table `account_following` is present in the database as you can see in the image below. I'm using `MySQL version 8.0.12`.

[image: Tables]

Comment: In hql query doesn't write the table name write your entity class name in your query

Comment: @Karthik But it's a `@OneToMany` mapping, what do I write then? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query to native Query.

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

@Query(value= "SELECT t FROM Tweet t, account_following k WHERE k.following_id = t.owner_id AND k.account_ID = :account_ID AND k.following_id IN (SELECT following_ID FROM account_following WHERE account_id = :account_ID) ORDER BY unixdate DESC",nativeQuery=true)
public List<Tweet> generateTimeline(@Param("account_ID") Long account_ID);
}
```

Since there is no Entity named **account_following**, you get that error in HQL.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question I have. Maybe I was not clear enough. What I'm trying to do is get a list of tweets from accounts. Those accounts have to be in the collection `following` in the account with `account_ID` in the query.

Answer (score -1):

If JPQL:

```
SELECT t FROM Tweet as t, Account as account WHERE account.following as f on f.id = t.ownerId ...
```

Note that above fields MUST be same with class fields, NOT column name in database.

Comment: Why would that make any difference? He is using a table name instead of an entity name in a JPQL join. It is invalid JPQL